# Can we run XAMPP in DropBox?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, cloud, dropbox

Is it possible to run XAMPP, PHPMyAdmin in Dropbox?

Answer (score 2):

Can't see why not but it's risky.
Dropbox will silently make .bak files for any files it tries to update (say they've been modified more recently on another machine) but they are locked on the local machine.  This can take ages to debug/find if you're not expecting it.  (For instance imagine apache is reading the php file while you're saving the modified version on another machine...)

If it's for simplicity of synchronizing you may want to look at some sort of source control like SVN/Perforce/Git.  You can get the server to regularly sync.

Certainly be interesting to know how successful it is with DropBox, I know for team collaboration on items such as Excel it's a nightmare when compared to true source control systems.

Don't get me wrong, I love Dropbox and use it regularly... just need to be cautious if you're regularly accessing files in it.